# Skip MoveNext() when throwing an out of memory exception in IEnumerator

Tags: c#, ienumerator, .net-4.7

I'm using `IEnumerator` to get all the files under a path, this could be more than 30 million files. For a couple of million of files my code is working but at some point in while loop I'm getting an out of memory exception in `MoveNext()`. Is there a way to skip the exception and call `MoveNext()` again to continue the process? Or is there a better way to do this?

```
using (IEnumerator<string> filepaths = System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles(startPath, "*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories).GetEnumerator())
{
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!filepaths.MoveNext())
            {
                //im getting OOM here
                break;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

I tried using this but im getting the same error.

```
foreach(string path in System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles(startPath, "*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    //do the processing in path
}
```

This is the **error** I'm getting:

> System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
>      at System.String.Concat(String str0, String str1, String str2)
>      at System.IO.Path.CombineNoChecks(String path1, String path2)
>      at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1.AddSearchableDirsToStack(SearchData localSearchData)
>      at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()

Comment: _"this could be more than 30 million files"_ holy.. what about enumerating each directory _(TopDirectoryOnly)_ so it would be less items per iteration?

Comment: Breaking down the IEnumerable to smaller collections could also be a viable solution.

Comment: Out of memory exceptions, along with stack overflow exceptions, are sometimes known as "the last drop problem". You've filled something (memory, stack, disk) and you're now looking at the piece of code that finally crashed when there was no more room. The problem is that this piece of code is just one drop in a big picture. I doubt `EnumerateFiles` will give you a out of memory problem so much much more likely is that "do the processing in path" part. Do you store something in memory for all those files? If so then I would look at that.

Comment: i already do a .Skip(i * size).Take(size) but at some point im still getting a OOM exception

Comment: @Lasse Vågsæther Karlsen  i tried to do a loop only without doing a process but still im getting a oom

Comment: `still im getting a oom` - even if you put that `foreach` in a standalone Console app?

Comment: @MatthewWatson that is exactly what i did.

Comment: `EnumerateFiles` caches the names of files and folders in a single folder. There is no way to circumvent this. You can only filter the search. Search all files that begin with some ASCII char, and iterate for all such chars. OR make your own enumerator that does not cache the names, but locks the folder until enumeration is complete. Starting point for coding is source code for [System.IO.Directory](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/directory.cs)

Comment: There is [code on CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1383832/System-IO-Directory-Alternative-using-WinAPI) that enumerates folders in a different way, but this code still populates a `List`, so it may throw exception anyway. But if you adapt that code so that `void Enumerate(..., ref List<string>, ...)` method becomes `IEnumerable<string> Enumerate(..., ...)`, use `yield return ...` instead of `retValue.Add(...)`, and `foreach (var item in Enumerate(subdir, ...)) yield return item` instead of `Enumerate(subdir, ..., ref retValue, ...)` then that might work for you.

Comment: @Dialecticus thanks man this could help :)

Answer (score 1):

thanks guys, i found the solution for my problem

```
foreach (string item in  Alphaleonis.Win32.Filesystem.Directory.EnumerateFiles(startPath, "*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    {
      //do work 
    }
```

Alphaleonis solved my problem